# What are the global all-caps variables defined in the example Todos app?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am reading through the Meteor example app "[todos](https://www.meteor.com/todos)" for learning purposes.

They use some all caps `var` and store them in `Session`.
It's defined at the first line:

```
var EDITING_KEY = 'EDITING_TODO_ID';
```

And used many times. For example:

```
Template.todosItem.helpers({
  //...
  editingClass: function() {
    return Session.equals(EDITING_KEY, this._id) && 'editing'; 
  }
});
```

```
Template.todosItem.events({
  'blur input[type=text]': function(event) {
    if (Session.equals(EDITING_KEY, this._id))
      Session.set(EDITING_KEY, null);   
  },
//...
});
```

What is it and what makes it special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EDITING_KEY` is a file-scoped "constant" defined in `todos-item.js` used to reference the currently edited item minimongo `_id` in the global reactive persistent client-side dictionary [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session).
It is used to avoid having to write the same string again and again everywhere, in that case `'EDITING_TODO_ID'`. Writing it everywhere can lead to dumb bugs caused by typos like your templates not updating because you wrote `'EDITNG'` instead of `'EDITING'`.

Since `Session` simply needs a string as first parameter, these two lines do the very same thing :

```
Session.get(EDITING_KEY)
Session.get('EDITING_TODO_ID')
```

The example project uses this multiple times to avoid bugs and make auto-completion nicer.
You can see some more examples in other files, such as at the top of `app-body.js` :

```
var MENU_KEY = 'menuOpen';
Session.setDefault(MENU_KEY, false);

var USER_MENU_KEY = 'userMenuOpen';
Session.setDefault(USER_MENU_KEY, false);

var SHOW_CONNECTION_ISSUE_KEY = 'showConnectionIssue';
Session.setDefault(SHOW_CONNECTION_ISSUE_KEY, false);
```

You could go further and define those in a global key registry that would make sure there is no duplicated key, for example with an underlying [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). That could be a fun thing to do to train.

Since Meteor now supports ES2015 this should be rewritten to [`const EDITING_KEY = 'EDITING_TODO_ID'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) to avoid overwriting it by accident.

Answer (score 0):

This appears just to be a variable that tracks what to-do is currently being edited. There's nothing special about it being in all-caps.